# Does the roomba 564 has a gyro?

Tags: ros, gyro, roomba-500-series

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm running the turtlebot, but not ont the iRobot, I'm useing a roomba 564. The thing is that when I try to calibrate it says all the time:
Still waiting for imu
Obviously there's nothing beeing published on the topics /imu/data or /imu/raw. I thinks this topics are related to the gyro. Is that correct?
I believe, as a conclusion of what I've exposed, that the roomba that I'm useing doesn't have a gyro. Can somebody confirm that? If that's true, how would you solve that?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11799/does-the-roomba-564-has-a-gyro?/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The gyro is part of the Turtlebot power board, not the roomba/create itself. You can find more details about the power board at [turtlebot.com](http://turtlebot.com).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-04**:
You can set the has_gyro parameter to false and then the calibration will run.